# ApexPages.currentPage().getContent() returns different value when called from actionFunction than from commandButton

Tags: visualforce, pagereference, getcontent

I have a visualforce page with the code below.  I am calling a apex method on page load that gets the pages content to send in an email.  The getContent function returns junk information if called this way.  If I call the same method via a commandButton, getContent returns the correct html.  Why is this?  I can see in the debug log that there is a slight difference in the pageReference.  The variable AJAXREQUEST is sent when called by the actionFunction.

actionFunction debug:

```
USER_DEBUG|[99]|DEBUG|System.PageReference[/apex/PaymentCancel?AJAXREQUEST=_viewRoot&com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateVersion=202210181905000187&j_id0%3Aform=j_id0%3Aform&j_id0%3Aform%3Aj_id38=j_id0%3Aform%3Aj_id38&prSetting=Payment_Request&req=61QK2IQW&result=cancel]
```

commandButton debug:

```
USER_DEBUG|[99]|DEBUG|System.PageReference[/apex/PaymentCancel?com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateVersion=202210181905000187&j_id0%3Aform=j_id0%3Aform&j_id0%3Aform%3AtheButton=Send+my+email&prSetting=Payment_Request&req=61QK2IQW&result=cancel]
```

---

```
<apex:form id="form" >
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!PaymentPostProcessing}" name="loadDocuments" rerender="form" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!PaymentPostProcessing}" value="Send my email"/>
</apex:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload=function()       
    {        
         loadDocuments();
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the `rerender="form"` attribute. If you add that to the `apex:commandButton`, you should see similar output. The fix is to remove this attribute if you want an apples-to-apples comparison. It's been a while since I've done this, but removing that attribute should result in your desired output.

Comment: You are right.  If I add the "rerender" to the button I get junk data.  If I remove it from the actionFunction the data is good but it continually refreshes the page.  How can I prevent this?

Comment: @Robinson Personally, I'd consider separating out this logic into another page, then use `apex:include` to load the original page and get its content.